# php string echoes as 0 when it shouldn't

Tags: php, syntax

I'm writing code to show the prices of some products. If the price is 0 it doesn't show anything.

```
<? if ($book->price_euro != 0) {$europrice = number_format($book->price_eur, 2); echo "€$europrice";}?>
<? if ($book->price_gbp != 0) {$gbpprice = number_format($book->price_gbp, 2); echo "£$gbpprice";}?>
<? if ($book->price_usd != 0) {$usdprice = number_format($book->price_usd, 2); echo "$$usdprice";}?>
```

This echoes "€0.00 £33.00 $66.00 ". The € price is set to 99. I can see no reason whatsoever that this should echo as 0! Am I doing something wrong? Bad syntax?

Comment: Echo out the prices without number formatting them, just to see what they are before you run them through the function.

Comment: can you add a bit more of the code?

Comment: I advice you not to use short tags [i.e. `<? ?>`] nor to make loosy comparisons with `!=` - use `!==` instead for being more consistent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$europrice = number_format($book->price_eur, 2
```

shouldn't it be `$book->price_euro` ?

Comment: how embarrassing! thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 6):

Typo in Euro

```
number_format($book->price_eur, 2); // This is what you have.

number_format($book->price_euro, 2); // This is what you need.
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything wrong with this code without seeing more. But maybe your variable?

```
<? if ($book->price_euro != 0) {$europrice = number_format($book->price_eur, 2); echo "€$europrice";}?>
```

`price_eur` should be `price_euro`?

Answer (score 1):

```
number_format($book->price_eur, 2);
```

should be

```
number_format($book->price_euro, 2);
```

The null value is causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might still be getting null values or something else try using empty instead

```
<? if (empty($book->price_euro)) {$europrice = number_format($book->price_euro, 2); echo "€$europrice";}?>
<? if (empty($book->price_gbp)) {$gbpprice = number_format($book->price_gbp, 2); echo "£$gbpprice";}?>
<? if (empty($book->price_usd)) {$usdprice = number_format($book->price_usd, 2); echo "$$usdprice";}?>
```